# Possible to change RSS default mapping

Tags: rss

When configuring RSS feed for a list SharePoint says: "Select the columns to display in the RSS description. Items marked with an asterisk (*) are mapped to standard RSS tags. For example, "Created by" is mapped to the RSS "Author" tag."

And so it does, the Title field maps to Title in RSS.

Is it possible to change this default mapping? I would like another column mapped to the RSS tag 'title'.

Regards

Larsi

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, could you post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the SharePoint RSS engine doesn't support this. You would need to create your own custom RSS output functionality or use a third-party solution.